# PrimeNG stop to open accordion

Tags: angular, accordion, primeng

How I can to force not open an accordion in PrimeNG. I mean in some circumstances I don't wanna that the accordion I selected opens. I tried in this way but it doesn't work

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/accordion

```
  <p-accordion #accordionQuestion *ngIf="questionItems && questionItems.length > 0"
                     [activeIndex]="currentIndexAccordion"
                     class="text-left mt-2 w-100"
                     (onOpen)="checkOpenAccordion($event)"
                     [expandIcon]="'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right'"
                     [collapseIcon]="'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down'">

          <p-accordionTab #accordionTab *ngFor="let question of questionItems; let i = index;" 
                   class="mb-2" id="accordionTab">
            <p-header class="w-100">
              <span class="w-100" [innerText]="question.code + ' - ' + question.text"></span>
            </p-header>
             <question #question *ngIf="i == currentIndexAccordion"
             (formValuesChanged)="questionChanged($event)"
              </question>
          </p-accordionTab> 

   </p-accordion>
```

where the method **checkOpenAccordion** is

```
@ViewChild('question', {static: false}) accordion: Accordion;

checkOpenAccordion(index: number) {
           if (this.currentIndexAccordion != index && this.changed) {
                this.disabledOthersAccordion();
                this.accordionQuestion.activeIndex = this.currentIndexAccordion;
           } else {
               this.currentIndexAccordion = index;
           }
}




  disabledOthersAccordion() {
      if (this.accordion && this.accordion.tabs && 
         this.accordionDomande.tabs.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.accordion.tabs.length; i++) {
            if (i !== this.currentIndexAccordion) {
              this.accordion.tabs[i].disabled = true;
            }
          }
        }
    }


questionChanged(changed) {
  this.changed = changed;
}
```

Comment: Can u create stackblitz ?

Comment: unfortunatly no

Comment: what you want exactly

Comment: I have some accordions.. in each accordion there is a form. If I change something into a form(so when is changed) if I try to click into another accordion I wanna to stop or prevent to open the new accordion clicked and stay into my current accordion.

Comment: can you make a stackblitz [here](http://stackblitz.com)

Comment: no because it's more complicated.. there are other components and services that I can't replicate

Comment: @travis_911 check my answer below if you any query then drop a comment

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to add some `input` method like this `(input)` on html example

```
(input)="FirstAccordion($event)"
```

For this you can check whether user something type on input field or not for example

```
let first = event.target.value;
```

After that you need to add `[disabled]="whatEverYouWantName"` attribute on every header for example

```
<p-accordionTab header="Address Name" [disabled]="address"></p-accordionTab>
```

if you want to first accordion close by default then add this `[selected]="false"` attribute on first tab for example

```
<p-accordionTab header="first Name" [selected]="true">
```

---

## Full Code Example

**HTML**

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="first Name" [selected]="true" [disabled]="firstname">
        <form>
            first Name<br/>
            <input type="text" (input)="FirstAccordion($event)"/> &nbsp;
      <button type="button">Save</button>
        </form>
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Last Name" [disabled]="lastname">
        Last Name<br/>
        <input type="text" (input)="SecondAccordion($event)"/>&nbsp;
      <button type="button">Save</button>
    </p-accordionTab>
        <p-accordionTab header="Address Name" [disabled]="address">
            Address Name<br/>
            <input type="text" (input)="ThirdAccordion($event)"/>&nbsp;
      <button type="button">Save</button>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

**TS**

```
firstname: boolean = false;
  lastname: boolean = false;
  address: boolean = false;

  FirstAccordion(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    let first = event.target.value;
    if (first) {
      this.lastname = true;
      this.address = true;
    } else if (first == '') {
      this.lastname = false;
      this.address = false;
    }
  }

  SecondAccordion(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    let last = event.target.value;
    if (last) {
      this.firstname = true;
      this.address = true;
    } else if (last == '') {
      this.firstname = false;
      this.address = false;
    }
  }

  ThirdAccordion(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    let address = event.target.value;
    if (address) {
      this.firstname = true;
      this.lastname = true;
    } else if (address == '') {
      this.firstname = false;
      this.lastname = false;
    }
  }
```

now forward you have to do some logic as per your requirement and on save button not written any logic you have to write on it

here is my stackblitz [Check here or preview here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jlhtx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: it's the same things that I do.. check my edited question. the difference is that I have a viewChild

Comment: you want this requirement and there are many ways you can do but you need to put logic   on that